# There is no template in my dotnet

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, template-engine

I have installed dotnet-sdk-2.1.105 on my Ubuntu 18.04, but when I use command dotnet new, I found no template in there
[The list of templates is at the bottom, but it's empty and no template in there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxKZZ.png)

Comment: What if you run `dotnet new --list` as listed in the usage text?

Comment: Still have nothing. I've tried to use command `dotnet new console -o myApp` to create a new console app and get an error message: No templates matched the input template name: console.

Comment: Do you have any other versions of sdk on the same machine? Does `dotnet --version` returns expected version? Have you tried to reinstall sdk?

Comment: I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my problem by using a previous version of dotnet sdk and dotnet runtime.